# Reference request about quotient spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$. Let $X/\sim$ designate the quotient space. My question is: are there some conditions we may impose on $X$ and on $\sim$ so that we can conclude  that an equivalence class $[x]$ is connected?

Comment: I think this is just a fact you have to check on a a case by case basis. If $\sim$ is known, the classes follow, and it's just coincidence whether the classes are connected (as subspaces of $X$) or not... Except the common case of a quotient map induced by identifying sets to a point, where the identified sets must be connected (by definition).